# Filter function in C++

Tags: c++, function, filter

I'm trying to filter some data via boolean functions. Here is my quickly written code, which has errors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Person
{
    private:
    
    string name;
    int age;
    double height;
    char gender;
    
    public:
    
    Person(string name,int age,double height,char gender);
    
    string getName() {return name};
    int getAge() { return age; }
    double getHeight() { return height; }
    char getGender() { return gender; }
}

Person::Person(string name,int age, double height,char gender)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->age = age;
    this->height = height;
    this->gender = gender;
}

bool IsName(Person p, string name)
{
    if(p.getName == name) return true;
    return false;
}

int IsAge(Person p, int age)
{
    if(p.getAge == age) return true;
    return false;
}

double IsHeight(Person p, double height)
{
    if(p.getHeight == height) return true;
    return false;
}

bool IsGender(Person p, char gender)
{
    if(p.getGender == gender) return true;
    return false;
}

class Group
{
    public:
    
    vector <Person> People;
    
    int getPersonCount(bool (*filter)(int));
}

template <class T>

int Group::getPersonCount(bool (*filter)(T), T t)
{
    int ct = 0;
    
    for(int i=0;i<People.size();i++) if(People[i],filter(t)) ct++;
    
    return ct;
}

int main()
{
    Person p1("Alice",24,1.80,'F'), p2("Bob",18,1.60,'M'), p3("Charlie",30,1.70,'M');
    
    Group g;
    
    g.People.push_back(p1);
    g.People.push_back(p2);
    g.People.push_back(p3);
    
    cout<<g.getPersonCount(&IsName,"Alice");

    return 0;
}
```

I tried passing the filter function as a parameter using templates. I'd like to know if it's possible to do that in C++. I know it's possible in Lua and I'm just not sure how this could be implemented into C++ code.

Comment: Too quickly written. There are some trivial syntax mistakes (missing semicolons and function call brackets) that distract from the question I think you're asking. The less noise you have in a question the more likely it is to get useful answers.

Comment: Once the trivial stuff is resolved, The parameters of `int getPersonCount(bool (*filter)(int));` do not match `int Group::getPersonCount(bool (*filter)(T), T t)`. Perhaps declaring `template <class T> int getPersonCount(bool (*filter)(T), T t);` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Unrelated: `if(p.getName() == name) return true; return false;` is just a cumbersome way to write `return p.getName() == name;`

Comment: Just for what it's worth, `std::count_if` does pretty much the same things as your `getPersonCount` tries to do.

Comment: Watch out! `"Alice"` is a String Literal, a `const char[]` of exactly the right size rather than a `std::string`. If your tools are up to date you can `"Alice"s` to get a literal `std::string`.

Comment: Applying my above suggestion, it looks like I'm wrong: https://godbolt.org/z/P9sYWvnzc . `template <class T> int getPersonCount(bool (*filter)(T), T t);` isn't sufficient. Resolving this is what your question probably SHOULD be. Unfortunately now that the trivial stuff has been answered it's too late to dramatically change the focus of the question.

Comment: The template signature should be `template<class T> int getPersonCount(bool (*filter)(Person, T), std::type_identity_t<T> t);` for the call to work. However you're creating many unnecessary copies of objects here: for every call of a function taking a `Person` by value, one copy of the `Person` object is created. You should instead take the `Person`s as `Person const&` avoiding the copy (this of course requires making the getters `const`-qualified. Furthermore for `getName` copying the string should be avoided;return a reference to const here: `std::string const& getName() const{return name;}`

Comment: Note that the `std::type_identity_t` in my comment above is necessary, since for `template<class T> int getPersonCount(bool (*filter)(Person, T), T t)` the compiler would try to determine `T` based on both the first and the second template parameter in `g.getPersonCount(&IsName,"Alice")` which results in a compiler error, since the compiler deduces different types (`std::string` for the first parameter, `char const*` for the second one)...

Comment: @fabian Note that `std::type_identity/_t` was introduced in C++20, so not usable in earlier versions (but trivial to replicate in earlier versions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `IsXXX()` functions are not calling your `Person` methods correctly, as you are missing the required `()` parenthesis on the method calls. Also, the return types on `IsAge()` and `IsHeight()` are wrong, they should all be `bool`.

The functions should look more like this instead:

```
bool IsName(Person p, string name)
{
    return (p.getName() == name);
}

bool IsAge(Person p, int age)
{
    return (p.getAge() == age);
}

bool IsHeight(Person p, double height)
{
    return (p.getHeight() == height);
}

bool IsGender(Person p, char gender)
{
    return (p.getGender() == gender);
}
```

You really should be passing the `Person` object as a `const Person&` reference instead, but that requires you to also quality your `Person` methods as `const` (which you should, since they are read-only).

But, that being said, the rest of your code is still not usable, because:

- your `Person::getName()` method is missing a `;` on the `return` statement.
- you are missing `;` on the end of each class declaration.
- `Group::getPersonCount()` is not declared as a templated function, but you are trying to define it as if it were.
- the arguments in `getPersonCount()`'s declaration do not match the arguments in its definition.
- your `IsXXX()` functions do not match the function signature that `getPersonCount()` is expecting anyway.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Person
{
private:
    
    string name;
    int age;
    double height;
    char gender;
    
public:
    
    Person(string name, int age, double height, char gender);
    
    string getName() const { return name; };
    int getAge() const { return age; }
    double getHeight() const { return height; }
    char getGender() const { return gender; }
};

Person::Person(string name, int age, double height, char gender)
    : name(name), age(age), height(height), gender(gender)
{
}

bool IsName(const Person& p, const string& name)
{
    return (p.getName() == name);
}

bool IsAge(const Person& p, int age)
{
    return (p.getAge() == age);
}

bool IsHeight(const Person& p, double height)
{
    return (p.getHeight() == height);
}

bool IsGender(const Person& p, char gender)
{
    return (p.getGender() == gender);
}

class Group
{
public:
    
    vector <Person> People;
    
    template <class T, class U>
    int getPersonCount(bool (*filter)(const Person&, T), const U& value)
    {
        int ct = 0;
    
        for(size_t i = 0; i < People.size(); ++i) {
            if (filter(People[i], value))
                ++ct;
        }
    
        return ct;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Person p1("Alice", 24, 1.80, 'F'), p2("Bob", 18, 1.60, 'M'), p3("Charlie", 30, 1.70, 'M');
    
    Group g;
    g.People.push_back(p1);
    g.People.push_back(p2);
    g.People.push_back(p3);
    
    cout << g.getPersonCount(&IsName, "Alice");

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/lWBZIIH3O)

That being said, you can simplify `getPersonCount()` a little by using a template for the whole type of the `filter` argument, rather than just the type of one of its input arguments, eg:

```
class Group
{
public:
    
    ...

    template <class Filter, class T>
    int getPersonCount(Filter filter, const T& value)
    {
        int ct = 0;
    
        for(size_t i = 0; i < People.size(); ++i) {
            if (filter(People[i], value))
                ++ct;
        }
    
        return ct;
    }
};
```

This then allows you to use *any* callback object that can be invoked with `operator()` and accepts a `Person` and a `T` as arguments.  Not just standalone functions, but also the return value of `std::bind()`, and lambdas too.

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/NjsvvOkCi)

In which case, you may as well simply get rid of your `IsXXX()` functions altogether and use [`std::count_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) instead with a lambda as its predicate, eg:

```
...
#include <algorithm>
...

class Group
{
public:
    
    ...
    
    template <class Filter>
    int getPersonCount(Filter filter)
    {
        return count_if(People.begin(), People.end(), filter);
    }
};

...

cout << g.getPersonCount( [](const Person &p){ return p.getName() == "Alice"; } );
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/ikxWsgj5JN)